Render face of a mesh using bpy?
Im trying to write a script for baking all the faces of a mesh with whatever renderer is used in the viewport.
At first, I was gonna move the viewport around and take "screenshots" of each and every face (and then assemble the images according to fit into the mesh UV map) - however I couldnt find a way of enabling near clipping plane in orthographic view(I need this to prevent other faces form blocking the view). So I then had a go using an orthographic camera instead (solving the issue, as cameras wont render what is behind them):
import bpy, contextlib, bpy_extras, mathutils
class ObjectMoveX(bpy.types.Operator):
    """My Object Moving Script"""      # Use this as a tooltip for menu items and buttons.
    bl_idname = "object.move_x"        # Unique identifier for buttons and menu items to reference.
    bl_label = "Move X by One"         # Display name in the interface.
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}  # Enable undo for the operator.

    def execute(self, context):        # execute() is called when running the operator.
        print("Meow")
        context=bpy.context

        # @note Basic camera setup
        bakeCamName="bakeCam8102361"
        bakeCamDataName="bakeCam8102361Data"
        with contextlib.suppress(KeyError):
            bpy.data.cameras.remove(bpy.data.cameras[bakeCamDataName])
        with contextlib.suppress(KeyError):
            bpy.data.objects.remove(bpy.data.objects[bakeCamName])
        camData = bpy.data.cameras.new(bakeCamDataName)
        camData.type='ORTHO'
        cam = bpy.data.objects.new(bakeCamName, camData)
        bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(cam)

        for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            if obj.type=='MESH':
                data:bpy.types.Mesh=obj.data
                for face in data.polygons:
                    face:bpy.types.MeshPolygon
                    
                    region3D:bpy.types.RegionView3D=bpy.context.area.spaces.active.region_3d
                    # region3D.view_perspective='ORTHO'
                    # region3D.is_orthographic_side_view=False
                    bpy.context.scene.camera=cam
                    region3D.view_perspective='CAMERA'
                    longestEdgeWorldSpace=max(*[mathutils.Vector(obj.matrix_world@data.vertices[vertexPair[0]].co-obj.matrix_world@data.vertices[vertexPair[1]].co).length for vertexPair in face.edge_keys])
                    # viewDistance=1.3*longestEdgeWorldSpace
                    viewDistance=longestEdgeWorldSpace

                    
                    cam.location=mathutils.Matrix(obj.matrix_world@mathutils.Matrix.Translation(face.center+face.normal*viewDistance*-1)).translation
                    cam.rotation_mode='QUATERNION'
                    cam.rotation_quaternion=mathutils.Euler(obj.rotation_euler).to_quaternion()@(  mathutils.Vector(face.normal*-1).to_track_quat('Z','Y')  )
                    region3D.view_camera_zoom=29.2
                    region3D.view_camera_offset=(0,0)
                
                    # region3D.view_distance=viewDistance
                    camData.ortho_scale=viewDistance
                    region3D.update()

                    bpy.ops.render.opengl() # @note Obviously I need to store the render somewhere as "Render Result" will get overwritten over and over again, but I'm omitting that code to keep this snippet relatively short

        return {'FINISHED'}

bpy.utils.register_class(ObjectMoveX)

Which seems to work just fine, however I really I dont like the idea of manipulating the Blender scene (adding a camera and moving it around) just to perform some simple renders/screengrabs.
Is there any other way that I could "render each face" of a mesh individually (that doesn't involve a camera)?
Thanks 

With Cycles you can use baking but EEVEE and the viewport renderer does not support baking.
You can't render without a camera. The viewport is also a camera you have to position.
To avoid other faces while rendering you can for each render change all materials so only that face is visible to the camera using Light Path > Is Camera Ray node.
To get a single face mask for each face you can set vertex colors for each loop via the Python API.
Mix Is Camera Ray with the face mask with a Math node set to Minimum and use it as a mask for Mix Shader for Transparent BSDF.


Thanks for the response.Maybe my question wasn't quite clear. By "Camera" I was refering to a

A Walter White?

Yeah lol, I hit enter and it sent the comment!

So what I was gonna send was:
Thanks for the response but I was mostly interested in ways that I can perform the actual render (as opposed to manipulate the scene or already rendered pixels).
My goal is to either:
A: get an array of pixels that describe a particular triangle of a particular mesh.
B: Get an array of pixels that describe the scene in orthographic view with the current viewport render properties, culling out anything that is behind a particular point in 3D space -  without involving a camera object.

Ive been able to figure out as much as that I can perform a "render" of whatever is displayed in the current viewport by https://pastebin.com/4jwwHiSm
Which works just fine, its just that the viewport has no near clipping plane whilst in orthographic mode, so if I were to use this to render out triangles, I would end up capturing too much of the stuff in front of the triangle (hence Im using a camera currently as it omits anything behind the camera, as shown in the sample code in my original question).

I suppose a shader based solution like you suggested could work, but again - I really dont want to manipulate the blend file (partially for performance reasons and partially because I dont want to upset people by breaking there Blender scenes when my addon fails)
// Willy Wonka (hehe, no thats not my real name :) )

The process should be real-time?

Not quite, but it would be damn cool if that was possible! I just want it to be fast enough to handle mid poly meshes without it taking half an hour to render.
For performance reasons, I'm however planning on using GLSL to assemble the per-face renders to the final image that fits the mesh UV map (I think I can figure this part out on my own).

You can write the data blocks to a .blend file, read the .blend from another subprocess Blender instance, render it and send back to the main instance. And why not just baking?

I don't use Cycles. Ive seen addons fire up background processes as well, its just that they're usually rather slow. I'm hoping for the entire program to run in a handful of seconds at most.

The subprocess approach is used in https://blendermarket.com/products/node-preview and its developer is the developer of https://github.com/LuxCoreRender/BlendLuxCore.
